# Meteor Leaderboard example with Owl-carousel

Tags: meteor, owl-carousel

I am trying to test owl-carousel with meteor 1.0.
Basically I tried to convert list as owl carousel in leaderboard example. but when I implemented it showed carousel but sometimes not showed carousel. I mean same code not guaranteed same results.
if it shows as carousel however the click event on the player element is not occurs.
How can I properly show carousel with click event on the player element using leaderboard example?

followings are how I did:

I created app using meteor from leaderboard example.

```
meteor create --example leaderboard
```

and added owl-carousel.

```
mrt add owl-carousel
```

I tried to convert list as a owl-carousel. I just changed tag OL to DIV and LI to DIV as below.

```xml
<template name="leaderboard">
  <div class="leaderboard owl-carousel">
    {{#each players}}
      {{> player}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>

  {{#if selectedName}}
    <div class="details">
      <div class="name">{{selectedName}}</div>
      <button class="inc">Add 5 points</button>
    </div>
  {{else}}
    <div class="message">Click a player to select</div>
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="player">
  <div class="player {{selected}}">
    <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
    <span class="score">{{score}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

and added initialisation function.

```
  Template.leaderboard.rendered = function() {
    console.log("rendered");
    var owl = this.$('.owl-carousel');
    owl.owlCarousel({
      items: 2
    });
  };
```

Here are the codes: https://github.com/sh1nj1/carousel-leaderboard/tree/owl-carousel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the divs you're trying to put into the carousel haven't actually been rendered when the initialisation code runs.  This is because the `Players` collection is being populated from the server, which will take a fraction of a second, so on first render, the `.owl-carousel` div will be empty, the `rendered` callback will run, and the div will *then* update with the player details once they're received (by which point it's too late to add them to the carousel).

To correct this, you need to hold off the initialisation until the data is ready.  The **correct** way to do this is to use `Meteor.publish` on the server and `Meteor.subscribe` on the client, which will return a handle with a reactive `ready` method that you can use determine when the collection is ready:

```
playersSub = Meteor.subscribe('players');

Template.leaderboard.rendered = function() {
  var _this = this;
  this.autorun(function(c) {
    if (playersSub.ready()) {
      var owl = _this.$(".owl-carousel");
      owl.owlCarousel({
        items: 2
      });
      c.stop();
    }
  }); 
};
```

Note that you would need to write a publish function as well, which I haven't included here.  An alternative, super-hacky way to do this would be as follows:

```
Template.leaderboard.rendered = function() {
  var _this = this;
  this.autorun(function(c) {
    if (Players.find().count() > 0) {
      var owl = _this.$(".owl-carousel");
      owl.owlCarousel({
        items: 2
      });
      c.stop();
    }
  }); 
};
```

That doesn't need a publish function, but assumes that all your players will be received in one packet, which might not be the case if you had a lot.  But it will get it working very quickly.

Finally, which package are you using?  `owl-carousel` doesn't exist - is it `richsilv:owl-carousel`?

Comment: Ohh, it seems to forget very easily that the server communication takes time. I am new in meteor world, so this is really good information. If I changed publish/subscribe model, I works well. but I think there is something duplicate to call players, because for "#each palyers" template, it calls helper "players" so I assume there is two same calls. codes: https://github.com/sh1nj1/carousel-leaderboard/commit/5772cb7e303613065b31bd04a3f96125d9f000ef

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, and yes I use `richsilv:owl-carousel`, it is automatically discovered I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

i was just a new starter for meteor so @richsilv answer helped me to start with a static code as per the demo of owl carousel.

all i needed to know was to put the code into rendered function. my template name was mainhome so i wrote the code like this

Template.mainhome.rendered = function() {
      $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        items: 5
      });
};

may be this is helpful for absolute beginners